# Problem with pointgrey camera driver

Tags: ros, camera, jetson, jetson-tk1, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was trying to use pointgrey camera with ROS on Jetson TK1. i am trying to install the driver using

*sudo apt-get install ros-jade-pointgrey-camera-driver*

But I am getting the following error :

*Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-pointgrey-camera-driver*

Can I know how to resolve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237585/problem-with-pointgrey-camera-driver/) by [asdfgf](https://answers.ros.org/users/26977/asdfgf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2016-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vtalpaert](https://answers.ros.org/users/27555/vtalpaert/) on 2016-10-03**:
Related ? http://answers.ros.org/question/48244/unable-to-get-point-grey-usb-camera-work-in-ubuntu/#240003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may need to install FlyCapture2 from the PointGrey website, at least thats one of the steps I needed to do. Also follow [this link](https://github.com/westpoint-robotics/usma_vision)  to a ReadMe on how to properly set your UDev rules.

---

Originally posted by [Shamwow14](https://answers.ros.org/users/27244/shamwow14/) with karma: 16 on 2016-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0